# Laravel: Dynamic Relationship in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I have a relationship on my Content model which is meant to be dynamic. I'm using content model as my post types, and each of them in database has a model value that redirects to a model which are the actual contents of the content type, that might be installed later using composer packages.

```
public function contents() {
        return $this->hasMany($this->model);
    }
```

It works when I use this relationship in my view

```
$type->contents
```

but when I want to eagerload this relationship in my controller;

```
$types = Content::with('contents')->get();
```

I get the error

```
FatalThrowableError in Model.php line 844: Class name must be a valid object or a string
```

I am yet to figure out why this isn't working or think of alternatives how I can achieve the same thing. I can provide more details if this is not clear. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** (temporary/permanent solution I came up with)
I removed the relationships and replaced it with this;

```
public function getContentsAttribute() {
         $items = $this->contents_type::with('user')->get();
         return $items;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using the FQN, i.e.: 
    public function contents() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Content');
    }

Comment: Yes thıs works if I had only one type of Content, currently my content types are Pages and Posts. Which are represented on the contents table with model values Socms\Content\Page and Socms\Content\Post respectively. -> http://i.imgur.com/ByE2pT5.png

Comment: Try this `return $this->hasMany(self::$modelClass);` make the parameter static ! Don't forget to set  `$modelClass` !

Comment: Ismail, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(temporary/permanent solution I came up with)
I removed the relationships and replaced it with this;

```
public function getContentsAttribute() {
         $items = $this->contents_type::with('user')->get();
         return $items;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your `contents` table is polymorphic and should, if it doesn't already, have both a `foreign_id` and a `foreign_type` (can be replaced with `content_id` and `content_type`). Then in your contents model you should have the following code:

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have tried this. This is not exactly what I'm looking for as $type->contents will now try to return the foreign_type with the foreign_id which I don't want to specify. I want it to return all rows belonging to a class without having to specify foreign_id.

Comment: I have edited my question with my temporary solution

Comment: Ah sorry for misunderstanding. I think your solution looks pretty decent to me.